# When boundary of union is equal to union of boundaries

Tags: real-analysis

I know that boundary of union is subset of union of boundaries. When  does the equality hold? Can you give examples where there is equality and where there fails to be equality?

Comment: Equality certainly holds when the subsets are either equal or open and disjoint. For an example of equality failing, think about two partially intersecting disks.

Comment: @EthanMacBrough, does it have to be open? I'm thinking of a similar example to two partially intersecting disks, if we take two disjoint closed disks, then the equality still holds

Comment: @dxdydz Consider $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and $(1,2]\times[0,1]$. Then the boundary of the union is a single rectangle whereas the union of boundaries is two adjoined squares.

Comment: I should clarify; the result may still hold even if the sets are not open, as in the question @Mariah linked. But in general being disjoint alone is insufficient.